# Google map handling in sencha

Tags: google-maps, layout, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have implemented the map functionality in my sencha based application. The map is showing but cant able to zoom in or zoom out & can't be able to move in other direction. It showa like static in the image.

[image]

But I want to show the map as like the following

[image]

Here is my code

```
  var mapapnel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
                                      id: 'mapapnel',
                                      layout:'card',
                                      height: '100%',
                                      width: '100%',
                                         items: [
                                                 {
                                                 xtype: 'toolbar',
                                                 ui:'light',
                                                 docked: 'top',
                                                 title: 'Find location',
                                                 items: [{
                                                         text: 'Back',
                                                         ui: 'back',
                                                         handler: function() {
                                                         Ext.getCmp('homepnl').setActiveItem(1);
                                                         }
                                                         },{
                                                         xtype:'spacer'
                                                         }
                                                         ]
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                 xtype:'map',
                                                 useCurrentLocation:false,
                                                 mapOptions: {
                                                 zoom: 15,
                                                 zoomControl : true,
                                                 center: new google.maps.LatLng(11.0183, 76.9725),
                                                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                                                 navigationControl: true,

                                                 navigationControlOptions: {
                                                 style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
                                                 }
                                                 }
                                                 }

                                                 ]
                                         })
```

what change required in my code add the functionalites zoom in & zoom out.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: It look likes a layout probem, try to put the map inside a container with layout 'fit'

Comment: thanks, its woriking fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my answer one more time:

It look likes a layout problem, the map should be inside a container with layout 'fit'.